# Best ASP.NET dynamic user control load approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a food menu ASP.NET Web app. I use a datagrid to display the menu items. When the user clicks an item in the grid, a user control opens up below the item to allow the user to enter item details and add the item to an order. The item detail user control in turn contains several user controls with RadioButtonLists, DataLists  and TextBoxes. The RadioButtonLists and DataLists are populated from a database. The user should be able to open and close several items at a time, like Windows Browser with sub-folders.

I've tried doing this with strait ASP.NET AJAX using ScriptManger, etc.. I set the item detail user control Visible property to True, and populate the list controls during the OnPreRender event. This is slow and sort of complicated because of the ASP.NET page/control life cycle.

I've been looking into using JQuery requests to ASHX files or Page Methods on the server to generate the item detail controls with maybe RenderControl and sending the generated HTML back to JQuery.

Questions:
Am I on the right track?
Would this sort of approach work for rendering and sending back HTML that may be complex and long?
Would JQuery requests be more efficient than my current approach?
Can anybody point me in the right direction for references and/or examples?

Thanks for the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a lot of help that led to my solution at:

http://weblogs.asp.net/sanjeevagarwal/archive/2008/07/22/Dynamically-create-ASP.NET-user-control-using-ASP.NET-Ajax-and-Web-Service.aspx